# Parsing Rails JSON Response in Android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm having some trouble parsing some JSON returned by my rails server in a basic survey Android app.

Essentially I want to first POST a response. Then save the ID it gets in response.

I'm getting the ID returned, however it seems to be `null` when I log it out while the other `"survey_id"` and `"appuser_id"` paramaters do get set.

Because my Controller is set with the params like this:

```
        def response_params
          params.require(:response).permit(:survey_id, :completed, :appuser_id)
        end
```

It expects my JSON post to be in the format of `'{"response": {"survey_id":"1", "appuser_id":"1"}}'`

Thus why I create a `ResponseDetail` to house those details in each response.

Here's the JSON I'm receiving back from my Rails server after the successful POST:

```
{"id":162,"survey_id":1,"completed":false,"created_at":"2015-03-17T13:31:10.403Z","updated_at":"2015-03-17T13:31:10.403Z"}
```

How I'm Posting it:

```
public static Response postResponse(Response r) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        String json = g.toJson(r);
        String responsesUrl = Uri.parse(RESPONSE_ENDPOINT).buildUpon().build().toString();
        Response resp = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = makeRequest(responsesUrl, json);
            String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 201) {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                Log.d(TAG, "Object is: " + object.toString());

                resp = new Response(object);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resp;
        }
```

Here's how I parse it:

```
public class Response {
    private ResponseDetail response;

    public Response(ResponseDetail responseDetail) {
        response = responseDetail;
    }

    public Response(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        String surveyId = json.getInt("survey_id") + "";
        String appuserId = json.getInt("appuser_id") + "";
        String id = json.getInt("id") + "";

        ResponseDetail detail = new ResponseDetail(surveyId, appuserId, id);

        this.response = detail;
    }
    //getters/setters removed
}


class ResponseDetail {
    private String id;
    private String survey_id;
    private boolean completed;
    private String appuser_id;

    public ResponseDetail(String surveyId, String appuserId) {
        super();
        this.survey_id = surveyId;
        this.appuser_id = appuserId;
    }

    public ResponseDetail(String surveyId, String appuserId, String id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.survey_id = surveyId;
        this.appuser_id = appuserId;
    }
    //getters and setters removed
}
```

Finally the Async where I post it. Where it logs out the appuser_id and survey_id appropriately but shows the ID as null.

```
private class PostResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                ResponseDetail detail = new ResponseDetail("1", "344");
                Response response = new Response(detail);
                new SurveyConnection().postResponse(response);
                Log.d("SurveyConnection", "Appuser: " + response.getResponse().getAppuser_id());
                Log.d("SurveyConnection", "Survey: " + response.getResponse().getSurvey_id());
                Log.d("SurveyConnection", "ID: " + response.getResponse().getId());

            } catch (Exception e) {    
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "It worked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Log:

```
03-17 08:40:52.225    3217-3233/getrewards.example.com.getrewards D/SurveyConnection﹕ Appuser: 344
03-17 08:40:52.225    3217-3233/getrewards.example.com.getrewards D/SurveyConnection﹕ Survey: 1
03-17 08:40:52.225    3217-3233/getrewards.example.com.getrewards D/SurveyConnection﹕ ID: null
```

Any ideas what I need to do to get the ID to be set? I tried both `json.getInt("id")` and `json.getString("id")` but they both seem to return `null` despite the fact that I see `ID` in the returned JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you´ve got `ResponseDetail detail = new ResponseDetail("1", "344");` and id goes null in there...

you see? it´s hardcoded, nothing to do with your networking

you should get the return value of this line `new SurveyConnection().postResponse(response);`

(By the way it´s crazy to read your code, everything is called `postResponse` or `Response`, even the request is called response! ^g^

Comment: OH DUMB! I'm not even looking at my response object. Yeesh. Thanks for catching that! I'll work on cleaning it up a bit - it was a bunch of copy/pasting from old code :)

Comment: java.user.CopyPasteException... it´s got lotta names, also Cargo Cult Programming

Comment: Hahaha. I love it. And too true... :D.